# Function error - name not defined

Tags: python

```
def getDetail(username, password):

    accountFile = open("accounts.txt", 'r')
    readFile = accountFile.readline()

    user = readFile.split(",")
    username = user[0]
    password = user[1]

getDetail(password)
```

I get the error:

> File "C:/Users/-/Desktop/-/quiz.py", line 151, in 
>   getDetail(password)
>   NameError: name 'password' is not defined

How else could I define it?
I am trying to split the two texts into two individual strings and access them through `user[0]` and `user[1]`. I've stored these in `username` and `password`, the parameters of the function. I want to do this so I can access the username and the password later on.

Comment: Why does your function `getDetail` has two parameters?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  ... when it should have none and is called with one :)

Comment: So I can access them in other functions or other lines of code

Comment: @MariusA.: Python has no *call by reference* so that is impossible. parameters are used to take input into a function, or to provide objects that can alter state, not to return things. That's why they designed the `return` statement.

Comment: @MariusA. that...doesn't work that way. I strongly recommend going through some tutorials. If you got that from a tutorial, find a simpler one.

Comment: so can I not do what I said above using functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't declared a variable called "password". In addition, you're not passing a username variable. A more pythonic way to achieve what you want is the following.

```
def getDetail():
    accountFile = open("accounts.txt", 'r')
    readFile = accountFile.readline()
    user = readFile.split(",")
    username = user[0]
    password = user[1]
    return username, password

username, password = getDetail()
```

Answer (score 2):

Assigning to parameters has no effect on the variables you pass in, and a function's parameters don't magically become globally defined variables.

Return the values you want from the function:

```
def getDetail():
    accountFile = open("accounts.txt", 'r')
    readFile = accountFile.readline()

    user = readFile.split(",")
    return (user[0], user[1])

username, password = getDetail()
```

You should consider picking up a good introduction to Python. Learning by guessing is very inefficient.